# Can I pass a parameter on grid's databound event?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Now I write the event three times:

[image: code snippet]

I have 3 grid in a view page,I use databound .Events(events =>
events.DataBound("onDataBound") on each gird,Can I pass a parameter on
the databound  event.
[image: code snippet]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
function onDataBound(arg) {
   alert（arg.sender.element[0].id);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```js
function onDataBound(arg) {
    this.wrapper.attr('id');
}
```

**Grid**

```Razor
  @(Html.Kendo().Grid<TwoModelInSinglePageModel.SampleModel>()
    .Name("grid12")
         .Events(events => events.DataBound("onDataBound"))
       .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
            .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.inx))
           //.PageSize(1)
            .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Test"))
     )
)
```

You can find `id` of grid. Ex:My grid `id="grid12"`